# how to find which object is causing "Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am not able to find which object is causing this exception. is there a way to find out which object is causing this exception.

I tried to debug the code but this exception occurs after the page load event

```
[COMException (0x80030102): Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CalculatePermissionsForCurrentThread(Object& pvarAcl, Boolean bOnlyAces, UInt64& pPermGrant, UInt64& pPermDeny, Boolean& pbIsSiteAdmin, Boolean& pbIsSiteAuditor) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CalculatePermissionsForCurrentThread(Object& pvarAcl, Boolean bOnlyAces, UInt64& pPermGrant, UInt64& pPermDeny, Boolean& pbIsSiteAdmin, Boolean& pbIsSiteAuditor) +252

[SPException: Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +146
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CalculatePermissionsForCurrentThread(Object& pvarAcl, Boolean bOnlyAces, UInt64& pPermGrant, UInt64& pPermDeny, Boolean& pbIsSiteAdmin, Boolean& pbIsSiteAuditor) +539
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAcl`1.CalculatePermissions() +163
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPAcl`1.DoesUserHavePermissions(T permissions) +97
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.CheckAdministrationAccess(UserProfileApplicationAdminRights rights, Boolean requireAllRights) +80
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.CheckAdministrationAccess(UserProfileApplicationAdminRights rights) +52
   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase.CanManagePeople(UserProfileApplicationProxy userProfileApplicationProxy) +50
   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplicationProxy.get_IsProfileAdmin() +61
   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileManagerBase.get_IsProfileAdmin() +53
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.MySitePublicWebPartPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +407
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4090
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a "using" statement in your code otgether with "Current" like so:

```
    using (SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web) 
    {
        ---
    }
```

If you are, make sure the site or web you are using is instantiated within a new object.

```
    using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
    {
        ---
    }
```

Comment: that is everywhere on internet.. I fixed this thing at first.. but still not able to  find where the problem is now.